# Why, for Graph $C_n$, the chromatic number is $2$ if $n$ is even and $3$ if $n$ is odd while $n \ge 3 $.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I can go to extensive lengths to show on graphs that if a cycle graph $C_n$ has $n$ as even that the chromatic number is $2$, and $3$ if $n$ is odd.

But when asked why I don't really know how to put it into words other than - "uhh- well if you use a graph it just works that way"

Is there any way that the reason why this works like this can be explained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that the chromatic number of an even cycle is two it suffices to present a coloring.

To show that the chromatic number of an even cycle is three we present its three-coloring similar to the previous case, but with one vertex of a new color. To show that two colors not suffices, we assume the converse. Let we have a two-coloring of the vertices of an odd cycle, say in white and black. Fix any white vertex and go from it clockwise along the cycle. Then along our way the colors of the vertices will change: white, black, white, black, and so forth. But, because the length of the cycle is odd, when we return to the starting vertex, it should be colored black, a contradiction.

Comment: Alternatively, in a $2$-coloring of $C_{2k+1}$, one color must be used at least $k+1$ times. The $2k+1$ edges see each vertex twice, so they see the dominant color at least $2k+2$ times; therefore one edge sees the dominant color twice, a contradiction.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Nice. I never thought about such an approach. I'll ask today our graph theory lecturer, how he would prove that $\chi(C_{2k+1})=3$. :-)

Comment: He said that a cycle $C_{2k+1}$ is odd, so the graph is not bipartite. :-)

Comment: That feels like cheating: "not bipartite" and "$\chi>2$" are synonyms. At some point you have to prove that odd cycles are not bipartite.

Comment: @MishaLavrov No, because we gave this as an exercise to our students. :-)